How to get all possible multiplicative combinations of $5$ matrices with unique output
I have a list of five $256 \times 256$ matrices. These are called generator matrices as their multiplicative combinations generate a "Stabilizer group"
Generators={G1,G2,G3,G4,G5}

These generator matrices also have the property that they are commutative i.e G1.G2=G2.G1 and they are indempotent meaning $G1^{2}=G2^{2}=\dots = G5^{2}=Id_{256}$
The stabilizer group contains all multiplicative combinations of these generators that give rise to unique elements (for example $G1.G2.G3=G2.G1.G3$, so only one of these are included in group).
I have done it out manually and there are $32$ feasible combinations: $$G1, G2, G3, G4, G5, G1^{2}, G1G2, G1G3, G1G4, G1G5, G2G3, G2G4, G2G5, G3G4, G3G5, G4G5, G1G2G3, G1G2G4, G1G2G5, G1G3G4, G1G3G5, G1G4G5, G2G3G4, G2G3G5, G2G4G5, G3G4G5, G1G2G3G4, G2G3G4G5, G1G3G4G5, G1G2G3G5, G1G2G4G5, G1G2G3G4G5$$
The code that I have tried to use to create the group is:
Stabilizergroup=
 DeleteDuplicates[
  Flatten[Table[
    Dot[Generators[[i]], Generators[[j]], Generators[[k]], Generators[[l]], 
     Generators[[m]]], {i, 5}, {j, 5}, {k, 5}, {l, 5}, {m, 5}], 1]]

Note when I flatten at $1$ or $2$ levels, the length of Stabilizergroup is $4$. When I flatten at level $3$, the length is $448$. Neither of these are correct, the length should be $32$. What am I doing wrong?
If anybody is interested in running the code, I obtained the $256 \times 256$ generator matrices as follows:
Id = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
Xpauli = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
Ypauli = {{0, -I}, {I, 0}};
(*You can get the imaginary i by "esc i i esc"*)
Zpauli = {{1, 0}, {0, -1}};

G1 = KroneckerProduct[Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Id, Id, Id, 
   Id];
G2 = KroneckerProduct[Zpauli, Zpauli, Id, Id, Zpauli, Zpauli, Id, 
   Id];
G3 = KroneckerProduct[Zpauli, Id, Zpauli, Id, Zpauli, Id, Zpauli, 
   Id];
G4 = 
  KroneckerProduct[Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, 
   Zpauli, Zpauli];
G5 = 
  KroneckerProduct[Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, 
   Xpauli, Xpauli];


Do not use uppercase symbols, they are used for the system. We may solve this using only abstract elements, without the complication of matrices. I note the abstract elements by : g[i]. We know that the multiplication of g[i] is commutative, therefore we may use the ordinary multiplication for these abstract symbols.
As the multiplication is idempotent, we do not want repeated elements. To get all ordered sets without repeated elemenets, we may use "Subsets". This produces a list of lists. To change the inner lists to a product, we use Apply[Times] (note that we profit from the fact that Apply[Times,{}]==1):
elem = Subsets[{g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5]}];   
prod = Map[Apply[Times], s, 1]

Length[prod]

{1, g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5], g[1] g[2], g[1] g[3], g[1] g[4], 
 g[1] g[5], g[2] g[3], g[2] g[4], g[2] g[5], g[3] g[4], g[3] g[5], 
 g[4] g[5], g[1] g[2] g[3], g[1] g[2] g[4], g[1] g[2] g[5], 
 g[1] g[3] g[4], g[1] g[3] g[5], g[1] g[4] g[5], g[2] g[3] g[4], 
 g[2] g[3] g[5], g[2] g[4] g[5], g[3] g[4] g[5], g[1] g[2] g[3] g[4], 
 g[1] g[2] g[3] g[5], g[1] g[2] g[4] g[5], g[1] g[3] g[4] g[5], 
 g[2] g[3] g[4] g[5], g[1] g[2] g[3] g[4] g[5]}

32


Let's work with sparse arrays because faster:
{Id, Xpauli, Ypauli, Zpauli} = Table[PauliMatrix[i] // SparseArray, {i, 0, 3}];

G1 = KroneckerProduct[Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Id, Id, Id, Id];
G2 = KroneckerProduct[Zpauli, Zpauli, Id, Id, Zpauli, Zpauli, Id, Id];
G3 = KroneckerProduct[Zpauli, Id, Zpauli, Id, Zpauli, Id, Zpauli, Id];
G4 = KroneckerProduct[Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli, Zpauli];
G5 = KroneckerProduct[Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli, Xpauli];
Id256 = IdentityMatrix[256, SparseArray];

All possible multiplications of up to $n$ such matrices:
mult[n_] := DeleteDuplicates[Dot @@@ Tuples[{Id256, G1, G2, G3, G4, G5}, n]]

Let's see how many we get:
Table[Length[mult[n]], {n, 6}]
(*    {6, 16, 26, 31, 32, 32}    *)

So we see that there are 32 combinations (increasing $n$ further than 5 does not add more combinations).
